# Method to_pickle increases the file size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pickle

I have a dataframe that I want to store and later access efficiently. From various forums, I got to know that I should use to_pickle method. But to my surprise, this increases the size even further.

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', sep='\t', mode="wb")  ## 650 MB output file

df.to_pickle('df.pkl') ## 1.3 GB output file
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Edit:
From the comments, it seems to_pickle is not for producing smaller files. In that case, what will be the best way to store it? It has only numerical data with most columns just 1s and 0s -- mostly sparse.

Comment: Pickling is something you do for serialization, not for compression. It's kind of superfluous to attempt to pickle csv files.

Comment: Have you tried to store as hdf5 with HDFStore ?

Comment: You can just write to a csv with compression if required, pickling is a string representation of the python object

Comment: My data frame is purely numeric and full of 1s and 0s. What will be the best way to store it?

Comment: Is the objective to save it in as small a file as possible?

Comment: Yes, but I should also be able to read it later fast.

Comment: I'm pretty sure pandas can read dirctly from a gzipped file. I would assume it has the capability to write to a compressed file as well. Try searching for that.

Answer (score 1):

hdf5 is a library intended for high performance numeric data storage. You should use it this way :

```
df.to_hdf('store.h5','df',complevel=1,complib='bzip2')
```

Comment: That sounds like a comment.

Comment: @cubic : You're rigth, at first, it was a comment typed in the wrong place. Then I improved it to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.to_csv('out.gz', compression='gzip')
```

You can then read it with the same compression parameter.

Comment: I do not really want to compress it. In excel storing files as binaries help a lot, but I don't see that making any difference in Python. Is there any way out?

Comment: The 2007 excel binary format (xlsx) is actually a zip file with a modified extension. You can change an .xlsx file to .zip and see for yourself :)  If you don't plan on accessing a file regularly than compression is the way to go, especially when it's so painless with pandas. If it's mostly zeros and ones than you can expect to have a good compression ratio too.